# Laravel OR operator in filter PHP

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm following [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IcLaNHxGTrs&lc=z231g1pjjr3rjly1oacdp4354ib34ofjnqucniy2totw03c010c.1506253493479421) tutorial to make filters on my site.

I'm trying to add an OR statement within the filter in the HTML.

For example,

```
<a href="{{ route('rooms.index',
    ['type' => request('type'),
    'sort' => request('sort'),
    'region' => 'Lisbon'|'Lisboa',
    ]) }}">Lisbon</a>
```

However, if I do this, only results for "Lisbon" appear, but those for "Lisboa" do not.

I have also tried

```
'region' => ('Lisbon|Lisboa'),
'region' => ('Lisbon||Lisboa'),
'region' => array('Lisbon','Lisboa'),
['region' => 'Lisbon', 'region' => 'Lisboa',],
```

all with no luck. 
It seems like when there is a comma between "Lisbon" and "Lisboa" that the operator only looks at the first option, "Lisbon" in this case.

*(If you're wondering, Google Maps API gives me either Lisbon or Lisboa for the admin district, even though I have restricted it to English.)*

Then, for my controller, here is how I am doing the filters:

```
  public function index()
    {
        $rooms = new Room;
        if (request()->has('type')) {
            $rooms = $rooms->where('type', request('type'));
        }
        if (request()->has('region')) {
            $rooms = $rooms->where('region', request('region'));
        }
        if (request()->has('sort')) {
            $rooms = $rooms->orderBy('created_at', request('sort'));
        }
        $rooms = $rooms->paginate(20)->appends([
          'type' => request('type'),
          'region' => request('region'),
          'sort' => request('sort'),
        ]);
        return view('rooms.index')->with('rooms', $rooms);
```

Any idea what could be a possible solution here?

Thanks!

Comment: The code you presented are just defining route parameters, not anything to do with the actual filtering of data.

Comment: True. Thanks @Devon I will add the content from my controllers.

Comment: Also, not sure what syntax you are trying to use with `('Lisbon')|('Lisboa')`.  This evaluates to a string of `Lisboo`.

Comment: To be honest, @Devon , I was trying several different ways and made a few up along the way... Sorry if that was a dumb attempt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Laravel collections include a `whereIn()` method to filter against arrays.  `where()` only accepts one value.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/collections#method-wherein

Therefore, if you are passing in an array of data as the region, you could do:

```
$rooms = $rooms->whereIn('region', request('region'));
```

**Furthermore**

A string of `'Lisbon|Lisboa'` is a string, not an expression.  You should not expect any code to understand that as two separate values.  Wrapping it in parentheses doesn't change anything, parentheses are used to provide an order to the operations, like in math.

`'Lisbon'|'Lisboa'` is a bitwise operation as `|` is a bitwise operator and not what you are looking for. `||` is an OR operator, but you can't just pass an expression as a parameter, you'll just be passing what that expression evaluates to which would be true or false if you use `||`.

When dealing with a list of values, you almost always want to utilize PHP arrays and array functions.  [in_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) is the underlying function that 
 powers this filter.  Be sure to understand arrays and review the available functions [here](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.array.php).

Comment: Thanks @Devon, but for some reason, I keep getting an error: (1/1) ErrorException
Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Comment: Sounds  like you aren't passing an array

Comment: You're absolutely right! Sorry about that. So, I did it like this and it worked: 'region' => ['Lisbon','Lisboa'],